# PHP Function behaving different on server and localhost

Tags: php, hash, rounding

I've build a class for a login system. I'm using a function to generate a salt key on 128 bits. But when I run this function on the server ( GoDaddy Servers ) it tells me that thr round() has a wrong number of arguments. Though I've tested it a few times on local host and everything is fine.

Could you take a look at it and tell me what is wrong with it ?

```
function encrypt($str, $len=null) {
 return (!empty($len)) ?
    hash('sha512', str_pad($str, (strlen($str) + $len),substr(hash('sha512', $str),round(strlen($str)/3, 0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP),($len - strlen($str))),STR_PAD_BOTH)) :
    hash('sha512', substr($str,round(strlen($str)/3, 0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP), 16));
}
```

Comment: I just found a solution, instead of having more lines of code to test the version of php and also apply another method if the version is older I just written this function and instead of round() I'm calling this function : `function round_up( $value, $precision ) { 

    $pow = pow ( 10, $precision ); 

    return ( ceil ( $pow * $value ) + ceil ( $pow * $value - ceil ( $pow * $value ) ) ) / $pow; 

} ` Tested it and it works. I found it on the php manual page. Thanks for telling me the origin of the problem :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are probably using an older version of php. The third parameter of `round()` was not added until php 5.3.0.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

**Edit:**

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0) {
    round($number, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
}else{
    if($number % 1 == 0.5){
        $number+=0.1;
    }
    round($number, 0);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I've read that, but I'm not sure which version of PHP the servers run. Anyway there is nothing I can do about their servers I guess, I could only find a way around this function or another method similar, right ?

Comment: You can call `phpinfo()` to have php print out version information. And you could just use an if statement to add 0.1 of the number you are trying to round is at a 0.5.

Comment: OK. So I check like this : `if(phpinfo() > 5.3) { ...instead of using HP_ROUND_HALF_UP I multiply it by 0.1 or 0.5...} else { ...do like I usually do...}` ?